# Different behavior when refreshing webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a widget that I want to modify when I load the webpage.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = someRandomNumberFromCalculation;
    $('#myWidget1').css({"position":"absolute", "margin-top": sum + "px"});
}
```

It works perfectly fine when I stay on the page while refreshing. What I mean by that is that I just reload the page, and just watch my screen as the webpage is loaded, and the widget changes just like I wanted.

But if I refresh the page, and for example I decide to change tabs to then come back to the webpage again when it's fully loaded, it will simply ignore the line about the CSS (or maybe it doesn't ignore it but revert to another one in the CSS afterwards).

I'm pretty sure that in both cases, the function is called, because when I put a `console.log("test")`, I can see the word in the console correctly.

I also tried using the `$(window).load` function, but I had the exact same behavior.

What should I do to have the exact same behavior even if I'm not looking at the webpage while it's loading?

Comment: If your page is loaded already, changing tab then coming back to the page tab - WILL NOT trigger document ready

Comment: @Huangism I may not have been clear in my question. Let's say my webpage take 2 seconds to appear and load. I decide to hit refresh, but after 0.1 second, I change tab while waiting for my webpage to load, and then come back after 1.9 seconds to see the end result. That's what I meant by changing tabs.

Comment: you could try `<body onload="somefunction()">` or use window.load or  [DomContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: the alternate was meant to see how it works without jquery, but re-reading I see the console.log test was actually inside $.ready ... correct?

Comment: @yezzz Yeah it was

Comment: does it work if you do for instance `$('#myWidget1').addClass("someClass")`

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350699/js-css-transition-when-window-not-active